# Insert and copy row in data frame in R

Tags: r

I have a large data frame that looks like this:

```
df
```

```
   X1 X2 
1  A  B  
2  A  C
```

And another that looks like this

```
df2
```

```
    Type Group
1  Train     A
2   Boat     B
3    Car     A
4 Hangar     C
```

I want to insert df2 into df1 and copy the entire row every time I insert so I end up with this

```
  X1 X2 X3    
1  A  B Train
2  A  B Car   
3  A  B Boat
4  A  C Train
5  A  C Car
6  A  C Hangar
```

What is the best way to do this in R? Cant figure this out.

Comment: Can you explain it please? How do you get the third table?

Comment: The third table is what I am looking to get. So I want to insert every occurunces of Group A in df2 into every occurences of A in df1 and copy the entire row each time I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your aim correctly, but below is my base R attempt

```
do.call(
  rbind,
  c(
    make.row.names = FALSE,
    lapply(
      1:nrow(df2),
      function(k) {
        cbind(
          df[which(df == df2$Group[k], arr.ind = TRUE)[, "row"], ],
          X3 = df2$Type[k]
        )
      }
    )
  )
)
```

which gives

```
  X1 X2     X3
1  A  B  Train
2  A  C  Train
3  A  B   Boat
4  A  B    Car
5  A  C    Car
6  A  C Hangar
```

Comment: This is close but I get an error message when running on the real code. "character string is not in a standard unambiguous format"

I also get a little bit confused about the nested do calls, lapply

Comment: Ended up using symmetri to create df3 and inserted df1 to df2 . This is probably a good answer though, even though it didn't work at the more complex real code. Thanks anyway